# ACPI shutdown not working from VirtualBox

Tags: 10.10, server, virtualbox, acpi

I have several Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) servers running in VirtualBox 4.0.4 (however this issue was also present in VirtualBox 3.2.8). When I issue an ACPI shutdown to the VMs, nothing happens.

I have added `acpi=force` to the top of `/etc/default/grup` (and ran `sudo update-grub`), and I have added `agm_power_off=1` to `/etc/modules`.

I am at a lost for what to try next.

Comment: Can you show us the log? did you try in your terminal as root  **VBoxManage controlvm 'virtualmachine' poweroff**

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu Server doesn't ship with ACPI support installed. See this thread for the original answer: [link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=39325)

To install ACPI support in Ubuntu, type this into a shell:

```
sudo apt-get install acpid
```